# What to do after cloning repo from git

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-clone, git-commit

I am just a **git starter**, basically I clone a git repository and now I wanted to commit the changes that I made in a file. when I run the command `git commit` it says `not a git repository`,

So being a starter in git i just wanted to ask that do i need to run this command first - `git init` and then `git commit`?  Or in between these some more steps to follow to commit the file?

I need to commit files on Bitbucket.

Screenshot-

[image]

Comment: I suggest checking out http://git-scm.com/documentation and http://gitref.org/index.html. They'll give you a good quick start :)

Comment: Also, you do not need to `init` cloned projects, only new ones that don't have git versioning the files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As *jeremyharris* said, the [git documentation site](http://git-scm.com/documentation) and especially the [online book](http://git-scm.com/book) there will get you up to speed on the basics.

A few quick notes that might get you past your initial issue.

`git clone` command is used to pull a copy (a clone) from an existing git repository.  By default it creates a folder in the folder you execute it from that has a `.git` folder in it.  The folder the cloning creates is your working copy and the `.git` folder is your local copy of the repository.

`git clone` is different than most other git commands.  All (or most?) other git commands require the command to be executed within the working copy folder created by the clone.  (Bare repositories are a bit different since they don't have working copies, but that shouldn't apply here.)  So, after doing:

```
$ git clone <remote repo> <repo name>
```

do:

```
$ cd <repo name>
```

to get into the working copy before executing any other commands.  Executing commands outside of the working folder will get you the `not a git repository` message.

After making a change to a file, `git add <filename>` adds it to the index (marked to indicate ready to commit) and `git commit -m '<commit message>'` will then commit the changes.

Comment: Just saw you screenshot, `cd wedding` before `git add .` and `git commit`.

Comment: ..thx I changed the directory and initialize git and then add and commit and iot works for me :)

Comment: thx for the comments..plz add this line in your answer .for future reference :)

Comment: you should not need to `git init` on a folder that has been created by the `git clone` command.  `git init` is used to create a new repository from an ordinary folder, which creates the `.git` folder.  It doesn't hurt anything to run it again -- it just should not be needed.

Comment: @Davis Culp, I edited your post to add in a missing '>' bracket, which was confusing me, and I thought I might as well throw in a couple of blank lines for good measure.  Sorry for the intrusion.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the change at first, use `git add .`

You can also check the status before adding, by using `git status`

EDIT

Just saw the comments about error. Yes that's correct. I neglect that.

Your problem is you need to `cd` the git folder at first.

After that, you still need to `add` as my answer above.

Comment: if git says `not a git repository`, it's obviously a problem of being in the wrong folder.

Comment: @BillyChan..so i dont need to run git init command? I can directly execute this add command ??

Comment: @NevikRehnel I just created a folder and run git clone command in the directory ..nothing else..so does it means i need to run git init command in this directory first before executing this add command ?

Comment: @BillyChan I just added my screenshot ..plz chk

Comment: @user1594368: `git clone` by default creates a subdirectory for the newly created clone (you would have seen that if you had just looked into your folder). You should probably read a tutorial for git that explains the basic steps :)