# What do I do after git clone --bare?

Tags: git, github, initialization

I have created a new repository on github.  I followed the instructions there and went to my local machine and at the command line typed

```
git clone --bare <repoName> <etc>
```

This creates a new directory (repoName.git) and everything seems to be good.  I have one source file I have already (previously) worked on and I want to add it to the repository.  I copy and paste the file into the repoName.git directory.

Back at the command line now, I type

```
cd repoName.git
git add .
```

This returns:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I have seen this message in several online tutorials and some StackOverflow questions, but none of the responses to it seem to be what I need.

My Question:
***Can someone advise me what I am supposed to do from here forward?***

Related:

https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.6/user/articles/creating-a-new-repository/
(Doesn't tell me how to add new files.)

[What to do after cloning repo from git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344832/what-to-do-after-cloning-repo-from-git)
This one looks like the OP has a different problem than I have.

[fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262801/fatal-this-operation-must-be-run-in-a-work-tree)
The most popular answer tells you what to do but now how.  If I knew how to implement one of his suggestions it would probably be the answer to my problem.

[Why am I getting the message, "fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456923/why-am-i-getting-the-message-fatal-this-operation-must-be-run-in-a-work-tree)
If the answer for my situation is in this question, I couldn't figure it out.  I tried 
    git config --unset core.bare
but it did not help me.

Comment: Why did you `cd repoName.git`?

Comment: Yes.  That is in my OP just before git add .   .

Comment: Yep, and I'm asking **why did you do that?**

Comment: Oh sorry.  I thought you didn't read my OP closely.  Turns out /I/ was the one speed reading.  Why did I do that? I thought I was supposed to.  What should I do different?

Comment: I would expect a directory called `repoName`, where did .git come from?

Comment: I am actually using github.ncsu.edu.  It added the .git extension to the repo name when it cloned the repository.  I don't know why. But I still have for myself a bare repository nonetheless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing : git add . will not add *every file* but only the modified and new ones (not those that are deleted). Maybe you should use git add -A.

However this is not your problem : When you use the option --bare, you don't download the working tree, you only download .git directory. See here : https://help.github.com/articles/importing-a-git-repository-using-the-command-line/

If you want to use the working tree just use `git clone YOURPATH`.
Hope it helps !

Comment: I will try this now.  Back in a moment.

Comment: This works.  This page tells me to use --bare, so that is what I was going by.  I have no idea why they tell you that.  https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.6/user/articles/importing-a-git-repository-using-the-command-line/

Comment: That docs describe how you copy a Git repo from `githost.org` (wherever that may be) to `github.com`. So you clone and immediately push the repo, no need for local files.

Comment: In fact many Github repo are used daily by developers : They often represent some tools that may be useful for a lot of person. Those developers will use this bare option to have a complete repository (therefore a working technology), but will not collaborate on the development of this repository itself (and so don't need the working tree).